# Are wheels designed for a maximum disc/rotor size?

Tags: shimano, wheels, disc-brake, size, rotor

I'm looking at some new wheels which Shimano describe as "140 mm disc brake rotor compatible". Does this mean they can't handle larger 160mm rotors? If not, why would they make this point, why not just say disc brake rotor compatible and leave it at that? Or specify some range of compatibility?

The wheels in question: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano/WH-RX010-CL-R.html

Comment: This spec line has existed for a while on the road/gravel Shimano disc wheels. I'm 99% certain it deals with preventing caliper interference with the hub or spokes and nothing else. It's checked as compatible for almost every wheel except a very small handful.

Comment: I'm still not sure how it is meant. Is it a "bonus" as in "it will even fit 140mm" or is it a limitation as in "can't handle anything larger" as suggested by the answer from Warren? My immediate thinking was like Warren, but I'm not totally convinced as you can see from my comments.

Comment: In other words it's a spec they stuck on after observing caliper interference with the spokes with 140 on some wheels, or something

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you think this is just a bonus spec. And using larger rotors is ok?